# Misunderstood topic

Tags: c

> Define a function CoordTransform() that transforms its first two input
>   parameters xVal and yVal into two output parameters xValNew and
>   yValNew. The function returns void. The transformation is new = (old +
>   1) * 2. Ex: If xVal = 3 and yVal = 4, then xValNew is 8 and yValNew is
>   10.

Question: I have to make this code, it is for homework in a text book. I'm not quite understanding the whole section. So, I'm asking for help and an explanation. Thank you!

My code is as followed:

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* Your solution goes here  */
void CoordTransform( int* xValNew, int* yValNew) 
{
   *xValNew = ((xValNew +1) * 2);
   *yValNew = ((yValNew +1) * 2);
   return;
}

int main(void) {
    int xValNew = 0;
    int yValNew = 0;

    CoordTransform(3, 4, &xValNew, &yValNew);
    printf("(3, 4) becomes (%d, %d)\n", xValNew, yValNew);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Read the "pointer" section of your C textbook. And compile with all warnings enabled.

Comment: `xValNew +1` --> `*xValNew +1` and so on.... to start with.

Comment: Be more specific. Mention the parts you _do_ understand and the parts that you _don't_.

Comment: Also, I believe you got some warnings. What do they tell you?

Comment: @SouravGhosh these are my first two erroes:main.c:6:29: error: invalid operands to binary * (have ‘int *’ and ‘int’)
main.c:7:29: error: invalid operands to binary * (have ‘int *’ and ‘int’)

Comment: A `void` function does not return anything. `void` is just required by the grammar.

Comment: @CoolGuy Well how I understood the section is that the * is meaning to pass a value from one spot to another. Therefore, What I think the program should do it pass the xValNew to my definition, do the work and return the value without me having to put in the return statement to return it.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie: I'm pretty sure I wrote "**`void`** is just required by the grammar", not "`return`".

Comment: @Olaf...ooops...sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You specs say "*... transforms its first two input parameters xVal and yVal into two output parameters xValNew and yValNew*" so your function should have *four* parameters, not two:

```
/* Your solution goes here  */
void CoordTransform( int xVal, int yVal, int* xValNew, int* yValNew) 
{
   *xValNew = ((xVal +1) * 2);
   *yValNew = ((yVal +1) * 2);
}

int main(void) {
    int xValNew;
    int yValNew;

    CoordTransform(3, 4, &xValNew, &yValNew);
    printf("(3, 4) becomes (%d, %d)\n", xValNew, yValNew);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: oh okay. So, what I'm doing is turning xVal into xValNew and same with y?

Answer (score 2):

the code for the CoordTransform() should be like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void CoordTransform(int xVal, int yVal, int *xValNew, int *yValNew) {
    *xValNew = ((xVal +1) * 2);
    *yValNew = ((yVal +1) * 2);
}

int main(void) {
    int xValNew;
    int yValNew;

    CoordTransform(3, 4, &xValNew, &yValNew);

    printf("(3,4) becomes (%d, %d)\n", xValNew, yValNew);

    return 0;
}
```

The main purpose for this exercice is to distinguish between passing parameters by value like xVal and yVal in order to use the values without changing them, and passing parameters by address or reference like xValNew and yValNew if you intend to change the value of these output parameters.

Comment: Variables `xVal` and `yVal` are not needed. Initializing the other two is not needed.

Comment: Why did you change the format specifiers? `%ld` is for a `long int`, not an `int`. Use `%d` instead.

Comment: you are right, I have made the changes you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

you are giving 4 parameters to a function that accepts only 2, and in your function CoordTransform, you should dereference the pointers to get the values

```
/* Your solution goes here  */
void CoordTransform( int* xValNew, int* yValNew) 
{
   *xValNew = ((*xValNew +1) * 2);
   *yValNew = ((*yValNew +1) * 2);
   return;
}
```

( the return statement is not needed since the type of your function is void )

Comment: this creates a ton of errors. I also know return isn't needed. However my teacher prefers that we do that.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem in my c++ class...
However I haven't learned C, so perhaps it doesn't allow '&' referencing? And only uses '*' for pointers?

My solution:

```
 #include <iostream>
using namespace std;

/* Your solution goes here  */

void CoordTransform(int xVal, int yVal, int& xValNew, int& yValNew) {
   xValNew = (xVal + 1) * 2;
   yValNew = (yVal + 1) * 2;
}

int main() {
   int xValNew;
   int yValNew;
   int xValUser;
   int yValUser;

   cin >> xValUser;
   cin >> yValUser;

   CoordTransform(xValUser, yValUser, xValNew, yValNew);
   cout << "(" << xValUser << ", " << yValUser << ") becomes (" << xValNew << ", " << yValNew << ")" << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

I used a previous example as reference:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void ConvHrMin(int timeVal, int& hrVal, int& minVal) {
   hrVal = timeVal / 60;
   minVal = timeVal % 60;
}

int main() {
   int totTime;
   int usrHr;
   int usrMin;

   totTime = 0;
   usrHr = 0;
   usrMin = 0;

   cout << "Enter total minutes: ";
   cin >> totTime;
 
   ConvHrMin(totTime, usrHr, usrMin);
 
   cout << "Equals: ";
   cout << usrHr << " hrs ";
   cout << usrMin << " min" << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

which outputs this (with 156 input):

Enter total minutes: 156

Equals: 2 hrs 36 min